# MacBook Pro Retina: huge power consumption

Tags: debian, power-management, macintosh, powertop

I'm currently running Debian/Jessie on a MacBook Pro Retina 10,1 15" (early-2103). Everything is going well (ethernet, WiFi, retina, etc.) but I worry about its power consumption.

laptop-mode manages the automatic power management of all my devices, all the tunables of powertop are *Good* and my i7 is running in *powersave* mode. The dicrete Nvidia video card isn't even running (Bumblebee/bbswitch turns it off as I don't need it). All bluetooth, card reader and stuff are disabled.

However, powertop reports the following with **no X11, keyboard and screen brightness set to 0 and all devices powered off**:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 15.7 W
System baseline power is estimated at 15.0 W

Power est.  Usage   Device name
692 mW  0.3%    CPU core
484 mW  29.9%   Display backlight
299 mW  0.3%    CPU misc
264 mW  0.0 ops/s   GPU core
0 mW    32.9%   USB device: EHCI Host Controller
0 mW    22.9%   USB device: usb-device-8087-0024
0 mW    12.8%   USB device: usb-device-0424-2512
0 mW    2.7%    USB device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Apple Inc.)
0 mW    0.0%    Audio codec hwC0D0: Cirrus Logic
0 mW    0.0%    Display backlight
0 mW    0.0%    USB device: usb-device-8087-0024
0 mW    0.0%    USB device: xHCI Host Controller
0 mW    0.0%    USB device: xHCI Host Controller
0 mW    0.0%    USB device: EHCI Host Controller
0 mW    0.0%    USB device: BRCM20702 Hub (Apple Inc.)
0 mW    0.0%    USB device: usb-device-05ac-820a
0 mW    0.0%    USB device: usb-device-05ac-820b
0 mW    0.0%    USB device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller (Apple Inc.)
0 mW    0.0 ops/s   GPU misc
0 mW    0.0%    USB device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) (Apple Inc.)
100.0%  PCI Device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
100.0%  PCI Device: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
100.0%  PCI Device: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Memory Card Reader
100.0%  PCI Device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
100.0%  PCI Device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
100.0%  PCI Device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
100.0%  PCI Device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
100.0%  PCI Device: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
100.0%  PCI Device: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
100.0%  PCI Device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller
100.0%  PCI Device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
100.0%  PCI Device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
33.0%   PCI Device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
0.0%    PCI Device: Broadcom Corporation Device 16a3
0.0%    PCI Device: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
0.0%    PCI Device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition]
0.0%    PCI Device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
0.0%    PCI Device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
0.0%    PCI Device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
0.0%    PCI Device: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
```

Manually doing the sum gives a ridiculously low value, but powertop stills report a 15W consumption.

However, running powertop in interactive mode in X11 gives me more plausible values:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 29.0 W
System baseline power is estimated at 16.4 W

Power est.    Usage     Device name
12.3 W    100.0%        Display backlight
8.01 W     29.9%        Display backlight
4.61 W     19.4%        CPU core
3.78 W    419.6 ops/s   GPU misc
3.12 W      4.3 pkts/s  Network interface: wlan0 (b43)
2.76 W     19.4%        CPU misc
1.35 W    419.6 ops/s   GPU core
188 mW    100.0%        USB device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Apple Inc.)
```

What? My retina display is consuming 20W? No way! (actually, with a 50% brightness it gives like 15W, which is *huge*). Also, sometimes the Apple Internal Keyboard is consuming 5 W.

It's not even a bug in powertop since my battery is indeed discarging very fast (like 2h30 when fully charged with only X11 running).

- Do you guys have an idea of what my problem is? I saw on other sites that some MBPr users report 10 W power consumption, or even less
- Why is there this huge difference between the "battery discharge rate report" and the "system baseline power"?
- Is that normal that my Screen and Keyboard use that much power?

I'm running a 3.10-3-amd64 stock kernel.

Comment: Do you get the same readings on OSX?

Comment: AFAIK, powertop won't work on OSX but I may give it a try. According to native OSX sensors apps, the power consumption is less than 10W when idle.

Comment: Almost 10 years later I've ran into the same problem :)
Manjaro running on a Macbook Pro 2014 (15inch) reports 25W usage.