# Powertop doesn't display Power est. column

Tags: ubuntu, powertop

When I run powertop, it doesn't display the "Power Est." column that shows the estimated power consumption in Watts of each row. It should look like in the screen capture here:
[MacBook Pro Retina: huge power consumption](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94515/macbook-pro-retina-huge-power-consumption)

But it actually looks like this:

```
          Usage     Device name
        100.0%        USB device: Biometric Coprocessor (STMicroelectronics)
        100.0%        Display backlight
        100.0%        Audio codec hwC0D0: Analog Devices
          7.2%        CPU use
        67067 pkts/s  Network interface: wlan0 (iwl4965)
          0.0 pkts/s  Network interface: eth0 (e1000e)
```

The "Power Est." column is missing. The total power discharging from the battery is reported, however. From lore on the net, I can find claims that it just needs more measurements before it will report this data, but no official statement or documentation of this fact. I have run `powertop --calibrate` several times, and left it running while on battery for hours now.

How can I get this column to display, or how many "measurements" does powertop need before it will display this?

```
$ powertop --version
PowerTOP versionv2.1, compiled on Aug 23 2012
```

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 (raring) on a Lenovo Thinkpad T61p.

```
$ uname -a
Linux compy 3.8.0-33-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 09:16:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried installing PowerTop 2.4 from source, but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

#### powertop

Sounds like you have to give it a few days to collect data necessary to perform these calculations, at least according to this AU Q&A titled: [Missed power est. column in powertop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291904/missed-power-est-column-in-powertop).

*excerpt*

> If you newly installed PowerTop, give it some time... It takes a few days to get the estimates correct and then starts displaying. I found this info on the net and also speak from experience...

#### powerstat

If you just want the power consumption you could use the package [`powerstat`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/powerstat/). There's a more thorough demo here, titled: [powerstat: Power Consumption Calculator for Ubuntu Linux](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/02/powerstat-power-calculator-ubuntu-linux/).

```
$ sudo powerstat -d 0
```

It will shows power consumption in watts

```
Running for 480 seconds (48 samples at 10 second intervals).
ACPI battery power measurements will start in 0 seconds time

Time    User  Nice   Sys  Idle    IO  Run Ctxt/s  IRQ/s Fork Exec Exit  Watts
 11:19:41   4.2   0.0   1.4  94.4   0.0    1   8731    518   20   20   20   9.44
 11:19:51   1.6   0.0   0.9  97.4   0.0    1   2165    301   20   20   20  10.78
 11:20:01   1.7   0.0   1.0  97.3   0.0    1   7788    400   20   20   20  12.27

Average   2.5   0.0   1.1  96.3   0.0  1.0 6228.0  406.3 20.0 20.0 20.0  10.83
StdDev   1.2   0.0   0.2   1.4   0.0  0.0 2898.3   89.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   1.16

 Minimum   1.6   0.0   0.9  94.4   0.0  1.0 2165.4  300.6 20.0 20.0 20.0   9.44
 Maximum   4.2   0.0   1.4  97.4   0.0  1.0 8730.7  518.3 20.0 20.0 20.0  12.27

 Summary:
 10.83 Watts on Average with Standard Deviation 1.16
```

Comment: The total power is displayed in powertop, it's just the power consumed by each device that's missing. I know it's supposed to compile data for awhile, but there's no indication or estimate of how complete that is. I don't know if there's a bug in my system or I have to wait longer.

Comment: @reasgt, same issue here, and I have given it days to run